# Tomee with C3P0 connection pool

Tags: java, c3p0, apache-tomee

How to use C3P0 connection pool with Tomee?

I included the below config in tomee.xml:

```
<Resource id="xxxx" 
        factory-name="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
        type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        JdbcDriver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP:PORT/DataBaseName;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;prepareSQL=3
        UserName xxxx
        Password XXXX
        JtaManaged true
        InitialSize 20 
        MaxActive 100 
        MaxIdle 30 
        MaxWait 10000
    </Resource>
```

But this is throwing an exception invalid type. Any idea how to setup this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write equal signs, your syntax is invalid. Look at this [example on gist](https://gist.github.com/maggandalf/7619729).

Your code should look like this:

```
    <Resource id="xxxx" 
        factory-name="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
        type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        JdbcDriver = net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl = jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP:PORT/DataBaseName;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;prepareSQL=3
        UserName = xxxx
        Password = XXXX
        JtaManaged = true
        InitialSize = 20 
        MaxActive = 100 
        MaxIdle = 30 
        MaxWait = 10000
    </Resource>
```

Comment: that's not the issue, type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" has not been identified.

Comment: sorry, couldn't comment with few reputation. How did you include the c3p0-library in your classpath? Did you use maven oder ant/ivy by chance?